# /usr/bin/npm: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, linux, npm

I run the command: npm install -g npm, and when I want to run npm I get -bash: / usr / bin / npm: No such file or directory.
i am on linux CentOs

Comment: Please follow the steps here: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#centos-fedora-and-red-hat-enterprise-linux

Comment: Have you installed `npm`?

Comment: Hi, wrong site.  SO is for programming questions.  Go to other Stack sites for Linux - Unix instead.

Comment: Hi! Did you resolve an error? I guess the problem came with -g . I want to swear really... I had a working project... Now nothing works... after I ran: npm install -g npm Which was announced to me in an official way... I cannot ask this question at stack for admins, because I have no points there since I don't participate there at all... Why would they run update in the way it ruins environment? I so regret I ran this update :0

Comment: Well I found how to ask question there... I will try to ask and if I have an answer I post it here in the comments.